# Ray Python code raise KeyboardInterrupt error, and if-else statement error did not worked

Tags: python, if-statement, parallel-processing, ray, keyboardinterrupt

My if condition does not work and let some code passing throught.
Here is the condition and print statement for debug.

```
def _run_remote_experiment(self, object_ids: List, id_config_mapping: Dict, pretrain_dict: Dict, exploring_feature):
    multi_runner_limit = 3
    if len(object_ids) < multi_runner_limit:
        obj_refs = self.run_experiment()
        object_ids.append(obj_refs)
        id_config_mapping[obj_refs] = config_copy(self.config)

    # control the number of concurrent tasks
    if len(object_ids) >= multi_runner_limit:
        try:
            print(f"Starting code that may raise KeyboardInterrupt...{len(object_ids)}")
            done_id, object_ids[:] = ray.wait(object_ids, num_returns=1)
            print("Code finished executing.")
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            done_id, object_ids[:] = ray.wait(object_ids, num_returns=1)
            print(f"Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.{len(object_ids)}")
        # done_id, object_ids[:] = ray.wait(object_ids, num_returns=1) <-- original code that doesn't worked
        output_list = ray.get(done_id[0])
```

I originally only have the commented out line, which did not worked. I change the line to try-except part and it worked. Below is the excerpt from my output.

pid=23544) [INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] === Start training on validation data ===
pid=23544) [INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] Start round validation
pid=22612) [INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] [round validation] train 1/1 epoch : loss 0.171, interval_acc 0.000, mse 0.171,
pid=22612) [INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] [round validation] valid 1/1 epoch : loss 0.035, interval_acc 0.000, mse 0.035,
**Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.2**
[INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] 51/351 ['log_close', 'm1_end', 'pbr']
[INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger] Write configuration
Starting code that may raise KeyboardInterrupt...3
pid=22612) [INFO 11:38:23] [ml logger]  === Saving last model before training on the Test data ===

It is hard to understand why such print statement(bold line) can be come out, where

```
len(object_ids) = 2
```

cannot be pass the if condition.

Also, I never touched Keyboard while the program running. This happend repetitively every time.

```
print(f"Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.{len(object_ids)}")
```

never work as I never type ctrl+c.

Also, above code can only yield
Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.0
Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.1
Received keyboard interrupt. Exiting gracefully.2

Comment: If you comment out `done_id, object_ids[:] = ray.wait(object_ids, num_returns=1)` from the try block, does it still raise keyboard interrupt?